# Can these plants survive spring floods?

Tags: identification, water

A maintenance company planted several plants just besides the river bank, actually in the area that is under the water for a week or several weeks in the spring (sometimes this repeats several times in a year, extending into summer and autumn).

These are photos of the area in question, and unfortunately I can't provide at this moment any better photo:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Just based on these pictures, do you think that these trees and shrubs can survive high spring waters? What are these plants anyway?

Comment: I see "bushes and trees" - if you want an id, we probably need a few close-ups of the leaves and bark and one overall picture of each plant. (One question per plant, please.) The trees *could* be willows, which are ok with being flooded now and then.

Comment: Are you sure you meant one question per each plant? There are hundreds of small plants (probably some ground cover) in the area in the middle of the slope, I don't think it makes sense to create hundreds of questions - one for each of them? It would take me days to do it... @Stephie

Comment: One per type - if you see three hubdred of the *same*, it would be one question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll just address part of your question regarding floods.

In my experience, after witnessing 2014 catastrophic floods in Doboj, BiH (where I live), I would say water level itself isn't going to be major concern for survival of plants and trees.

During three days, we had water level up to 4 meters, which is enough to flood most smaller trees. After water has return to river beds, most of vegetation has fully recovered and maybe even flourished afterwards. But there were few cases where huge, old trees were completely pulled from ground.

In my opinion, biggest issue is destructive power of water especially with flash floods. Water front is certainly able to pull out even the biggest trees, move large objects and create landslides.

[image: Doboj flood 2014]

Comment: Hope you and your family are well now.